# What is the determinant of Ad(g)?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups

In more generality, if a matrix acts on a group of matrices by conjugation, what is the determinant of this action (if such a notion exists)? Is it simply the determinant of the matrix being used to conjugate?

In particular, given a Lie group $G$, with $g \in G$, we have a map
$$
Int_g:G \to G, x \mapsto gxg^{-1}.
$$
Differentiating this action gives a map
$$
Ad_g: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}.
$$
Thus we have a map
$$
Ad: G \to Aut(\mathfrak{g}).
$$
If $G = GL(n,\mathbb{C})$, we have that $G$ acts by
$$
g \cdot X = gXg^{-1},
$$
for $g \in G, X \in \mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$.

A few of the sources I have been using refer to the determinant of this action; how is this calculated? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What books/note are you using?

Comment: @John The encyclopedia of mathematics says an equivalent definition of a unimodular group (when G is a Lie group) is the condition that $| det Ad(g)| = 1$ for all $g \in G$.

Comment: For the case of linear groups, you just have to write in a basis, say $e_{ij}$ (a matrix with $1$ in $(i, j)$). For the general case, you will have to compute the matrix given by the differential of the translations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g\in G$ and $f:X\in M_n\rightarrow gXg^{-1}$. Then $f=g\otimes g^{-T}$ -if we stack the matrices row by row- cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product
If $spectrum(g)=(\lambda_i)_i$, then $spectrum(f)=\{\lambda_i/\lambda_j|i,j\}$. Finally $\det(f)=1$.

Comment: I'm a little confused; wouldn't this imply that all Lie groups are unimodular?

Comment: All that this shows is that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is unimodular.